# Can the .exe run on Mac, Linux, or other platforms?

Tags: python, windows

I created a .exe out of .py by using the **PyInstaller** on Windows. Can this .exe run on Mac, Linux, or other platforms?

Comment: No, it can't. Leave it as a Python file and you can run it anywhere.

Comment: Yes it can via a windows emulator like Wine or a VM with windows installed. But this isn't a python question, its about running windows apps on linux/mac and is better over at superuser.com or serverfault.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Executable formats for Windows are completely different from those used on other OSes. You might be able to run them in Linux under WINE, but they're not natively compatible with any other OS.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the answers here for linux and windows https://superuser.com/questions/216629/can-i-run-a-windows-exe-file-on-linux

As for mac, no .exe will not work.

In general, pyinstaller would have to be run on each os to make an executable specifically for that os.